# sqlite setup with gui

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite command line and works fine, but when it comes to the gui, there's the problem. I installed both Database Master and Expert Professional. When I create a random database and import a ready-made .sql script, I get a "syntax" error. Eventhough .read works and the database is executed in command line.

Error Expert Professional (similar to Database Manager): **Data transfer error: near ".": syntax error**

Any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe locate and post the offending SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I had to delete some commands that don't work in gui but work in command-line.